# SegmentedControl breaks when using ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I am trying out SwiftUI and unfortunately it still has some issues but I dont know if its on my side or its just buggy. I am trying to use a SegmentedControl alongside a ForEach which displays images but labels of SegmentedControl is gone.

This is my ContentView:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var filter = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SegmentedControl(selection: $filter) {
                Text("Tag1").tag(0)
                Text("Tag2").tag(1)
            }.padding(.bottom)
            ForEach(1...3) { spot in
                ZStack {
                    Image("placeholder")
                        .frame(height: 200)
                        .clipped()
                    Text("Swift")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }.padding(.bottom, -8)
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Explore"))
        }
    }
}
```

I dont see why it should break but it does. Am I using it wrongly or is this just a bug?

[image: preview]

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code (and swapped out your image with the "turtlerock" one from the swiftui tutorial), and everything showed up fine. If the image above is a preview, try running the app. If it still doesn't look like it's supposed to, try removing the rendering adjustments (`clipped` and `frame`), and try the general stuff (cleaning the build folder and re-running, restarting xcode, etc.) If it still doesn't work then its likely a bug with Xcode 11 beta.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SegmentedControl` is stretched and the reason is your image. The `SegmentedControl`'s width is stretched to the size of the image and you're setting a custom frame to the image without making it resizable. That's why your labels are out of bounds. Just add `.resizable()` to your image, this will fix your image's size and your labels will also appear:

```
Image("placeholder")
  .resizable()
  .frame(height: 200)
  .clipped()
```